# In Google Sheets how do I return the total number of scenarios that match two conditions?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-query

I am creating a summary within a large spreadsheet and want to be able to show the total number of items that meet two criteria.

Criteria A is in a range in one column, and Criteria B in another. Both of these criteria are in the same sheet but one is Text and one is a checkbox.

Criteria A is a type and Criteria B is checkbox to show whether that type is a particular version number e.g box checked means 'Yes'. The purpose of the summary and why I want to calculate this is because I have a number of 'Types' with a number of 'Versions' and I want to see how many of each.

I've tried a number of formula, COUNTIFS, DCOUNTA, ARRAY - stabbing around to see if anything will work...no joy!

If there is a way to do this with the checkboxes remaining that would be great, but I guess I could also change the second criteria to a numeric value. But I am still not sure which formula for the two criteria together to get the output I want.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange (https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour). Please show a table with sample data and your desired results from that data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you tried?:

> =Countifs(A:A,"type",B:B,true)

Comment: Thank you, yes I have tried this and it returns a 0 when I know that the value I want to see is 2....I purposefully have used a small sample here to be able to corroborate what I get it correct.

I did this first and got 0

=countifs('All WIB Sites'!B:B,"Base",'All WIB Sites'!G:G,"true")

I tried this too wondering if I needed to be more specific on the range:

=countifs('All WIB Sites'!B3:B100,"Base",'All WIB Sites'!G3:G100,"true")

Also returned 0

Comment: But have you tried with True without quotations marks?? It works as far as I have tried

Comment: I have now - interestingly the value for one type of criteria is pulling through, but it is incorrect by the value of 1.

Comment: Mmm, that is odd... maybe some extra space in column A??, maybe if the type is "Product" but you have "Product " it won't be counted

Comment: I've jiggled the data again, that seems to have done the trick. Thank you very much!